# dynamically dropdown in nodejs mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax, html

I want to change the region according to the clients when a user click and select a client then the region dropdown change according to the region that are related to that client from database`enter code here`

**Here is my client table:**
[image: Here is my client table]

**Here is my Region table in which client_id is the foreign key:**
[image: Here is my Region table in which client_id is the foreign key]

This is my code

```html
<div class="container">
  <h3>Add Area</h3>

  <form action="/add_areas" method="POST">
   
    <!--input type="text" placeholder="DistributorID" name="distributor_id"-->
    <input type="text" placeholder="Area Name" name="area_name" required="">
    <!-- <input type="text" placeholder="Contact ID" name="contact_id" required=""> -->

    <!-- <label>Client ID</label> -->
    <select name="client_id" required="">
     <option disabled selected value> -- select a Client  -- </option>
     <%for(i=0; i<clients.length; i++){%>
      <option value="<%= clients[i].id%>"><%= clients[i].client_name %></option>
     <%}%>
    </select>

    <select name="region_id" required="">
     <option disabled selected value> -- select a Region  -- </option>
     <%for(i=0; i<regions.length; i++){%>
      <option value="<%= regions[i].id%>"><%= regions[i].region_name %></option>
     <%}%>
    </select>
    <br>
    
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>

  <br>
  <%if(areas.length>0) { %>
   <h3>All Existing Areas</h3>
   <!--For view-->
   <div class="table-rsponsive"> 
       <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-sm " cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
         <th>Area Name</th>
         <th>Client </th>
         <th>Region </th>
         <th colspan="2">Action</th>
        </tr>
      <% for(var i=0; i<areas.length; i++) {%>
        <tr>
          <td><%= areas[i].area_name %></td>
          <td><%= areas[i].client_name %></td>
          <td><%= areas[i].region_name %></td>

          <td><a href="/edit_areas/<%= areas[i].id %>"><button class="btn-primary">Edit</button></a></td>
          <td><a href="/delete_areas/<%= areas[i].id %>" onclick="javascript: return confirm('Are you SURE? If you delete this area All the town belongs to <%= areas[i].area_name %> area will automatically deleted!!');"><button class="btn-danger">Delete</button></a></td>
        </tr>
      <% } %>
    </table>
   </div>
   <% } 
   else{ %>
   <h3>No Area Found!!</h3>
  <% } %>
 
  <!--goto dashboard button-->
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" onclick="window.location.href='/dashboard.html'">Return to dashboard</button>
 </div>
```

**Here is the page to add area:**
[Here is the page to add area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sS9YE.png)

Comment: I want to do like that https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/dynamically-fill-html-dropdown-option-values-using-javascript/ by using the values from database not hard coded.

Comment: https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/dynamically-fill-html-dropdown-option-values-using-javascript/ . I want the output like the output in that link but in this link the input is hard coded I want the according to the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, solution boils down to the following:

```
//These are your target elements
const client = document.querySelector('#client');
const region = document.querySelector('#region');
const table = document.querySelector('#table');
//POST username upon change event and modify table 'div' and region'select' innerHTML's accordingly
client.addEventListener('change', function () {
    let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    let user = this.value;
    xhr.open('POST', '/getRegionsByUser', true);
    xhr.send(user);
    xhr.onload = function(){
        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            let regions = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            /* expected JSON-formatted string {list:[region1, region2, ...] */
            regions.list.forEach(region => {
                region.innerHTML += '<option value="'+region+'">'+region+'</option>';
                table.innerHTML += '...';
            });
        }
    };
});
```

server-side scripting depends heavily on your environment, conceptually, it is supposed to do SQL-select regions by username and responding with JSON-formatted list

Comment: How I can display the result from mysql. When I have selected client on the first dropdown and then display the regions on the second dropdown according to that client from database??

Comment: The Client is not hard coded it can be change, one client may have multiple regions and I want a solution that can be changed accordingly.

Comment: and when we select a client then only those regions belongs to that client appears on the regions drop down

Comment: I want to do like that https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/dynamically-fill-html-dropdown-option-values-using-javascript/ by using the values from database

Comment: You may POST your client_id to the server, do `SELECT region_name FROM regions WHERE client_id={received_value}` server side, respond with query results, and change your div and dropdown contents. That's roughly the logic.

Comment: yes Sir!! I know but how can I send it.Because I do not know about ajax

Comment: https://www.js-tutorials.com/javascript-tutorial/dynamically-fill-html-dropdown-option-values-using-javascript/ . I want the output like the output in that link but in this link the input is hard coded I want the output according to the database.

Comment: Sir, I am thinking that you does not clearly understand the question, Now the question is that I want to make two dropdowns one of country and the second is city and when the user select the country from the first dropdown then in the second dropdown the cities of that country will be shown but from database.

Comment: Lol. Your question context is changing faster, than I'm posting the answers. You started in your question header with 'populate one dropdown', then it turned out to be 'one dropdown and a div', now it's 'two dropdowns and a div' and God knows where you're going to end up. That makes me think that it's you, in the first place, who don't clearly understand the question.

Comment: However, logic demonstrated above, is easily extendable for arbitrary number of elements and, I believe, you, or whoever contributing minimum effort, may comprehend that and implement in the necessary way, which is enough for me to give up on this particular topic at this point.

Comment: Thanks for your kind support

Comment: and by the way I am not changing my question if you see my code then there are two dropdowns first of client and the second dropdown is region which will be change according to the client dropdown this is the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add a ajax request on onChange event for field_id=**client_id** to fetch regions based on selected **client_id**. For response you can design server according to your need, you can either generate HTML at server side or can get raw result from database in response and then generate HTML from it at client side. When you get the well suited HTML format for select options then append that html to **region_id** select.

Comment: How can I add ajax. could you help me