# Dynamic drop down menu node js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, ajax, ejs

I'm new to node. I need to make a dependent dropdown menu which gets the address data of the selected user from another dropdown menu in the same page..The proplem is that the hole page is updated not only the second dropdown menu..  I think it's the same problem as [dynamically dropdown in nodejs mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53929388/dynamically-dropdown-in-nodejs-mysql), but it didn't help me much.

```
<select name="selectUser" id="user" >
  <option disabled selected> Select User..</option>
  <% users.forEach((users) => { %>
    <option value="<%= users.id %>" > <%=users.name %> </option>
  <%  })  %>
</select>
<br>
<label>Address :</label>
<select name="selectAddress" id="address">
  <option disabled selected> Select Address..</option>
  <% address.forEach((address) => { %>
    <option value="<%= address.addressId %>" > <%=address.addressName %> </option>
</select>
  <%  })  %>
```

my ajax request:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#user').change(function(){

   var item =  $('#user').val();
   var add  = $('#address').val();
   $.ajax({
       type:'GET',
       data: {selectedId : item },
       url:'/order/new',
       success: function(result1){
           $('#body').html(result1);

       }
   });
  });
});
```

order.js

```
 module.exports = {
      addOrderPage: (req, res) => {
    let query1 = "SELECT * FROM users";
    getConnection().query(query1, (err, result1) => {
            let query2 = "SELECT * FROM address WHERE userId = '" +req.query.selectedId + "'";
            getConnection().query(query2, (err, rows, fields) => {
              if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
              }
               console,log(rows)
              res.render('newOrder.ejs', {
                  address : rows,
                  users: result1
              });
              });
    });
}
    }
```

app.js

```
app.get('/order/new', addOrderPage)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your success function has missing the data that is return from request update your success function

```
       $(document).ready(function(){
       $('#user').change(function(){ 

        var item = $('#user').val();

        $.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            data: { selectedId: item },
            url:'/users/address',
            success: function(data){
                console.log(data);
                 $('#address').empty();
             $('address').append("<option disabled selected> Select Address..</option>");
             $.each(data, function (index, addressObj) {
                    $('#address').append("<option value = '" + addressObj.id + "' > " + addressObj.first_name + ". </option > ");
                });
            }
        });
       });
```

And in your order.js you need create one call for users and one call is for usersaddress data:-

```
      module.exports = {
    addOrderPage: (req, res) => {
        var selecteduser = req.query.selectedId;
        let query1 = "SELECT * FROM users";
        db.query(query1, (err, result1) => {
                if (err) {
                    return res.status(500).send(err);
                }
                res.render('newOrder.ejs', {
                    players: result1,
                });
        });
    },
    getUserAddress: (req, res) => {
        var selecteduser = req.query.selectedId;
        let query1 = "SELECT * FROM address WHERE userId = '" + selectedId + "'";
        db.query(query1, (err, result1) => {
            if (err) {
                return res.status(500).send(err);
            }
            res.send(result1);
        });
    }
}
```

neworder.js

```
 <select name="selectUser" id="user" >
    <option disabled selected> Select User..</option>
     <% users.forEach((users) => { %>
    <option value="<%= users.id %>" > <%=users.name %> </option>
    <%  })  %>
 </select>
 <br>
 <label>Address :</label>
 <select name="selectAddress" id="address">
  <option disabled selected> Select Address..</option>
 </select>
```

And in your app.js or index.js you need to add its route

```
 app.use("/users/address", order.getUserAddress);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me..I want to grap data in the address dropdown menu from address table which connect with users table in userId

Comment: Try to `console.log(data)` and check what it is returning.

Comment: Also try to update your `url : 'http:yourprojectport/order/new'`

Comment: I got this errot: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0..& I'm not sure of me data request in the ajax function

Comment: Try to directly access the `url` in your browser check it is returning result or not

Comment: yes i got a result & the first user dropdown menu is empty when i choose one user of it

Comment: Check the updated code you need to do some changes as above

Comment: it return an alert whih contains [object,object]

Comment: Check and update your code that as i have made changes

Comment: okay i think res function doesn't work cause it reurn an empty array in the whole page!!

Comment: Yes you need to define two different routes for different functionality one is for rendering user and index page and on other method you will return address of the user that you select in the dropdown as I shown above

Comment: I got the error that address isn't define..in my ejs file.

Comment: You need to create just empty select tag and when you select user from dropdown ajax will call data for address select box so change your select tag code for address with this `<select name="selectAddress" id="address">
  <option disabled selected> Select Address..</option>
</select>`

Comment: okay I did that but I got this Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'length' in

Comment: I updated my question as I make some changes..If you could help me, I'll be thankful.

Comment: I have made some little changes try the above code now.

Comment: IT WORKED.. YOU SAVED MY LIFE

Comment: but can you explain why you use app.use();

Comment: Check this link [express-routing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15601703/difference-between-app-use-and-app-get-in-express-js)